# Unlocking all decks in Magic DotP 2014

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2014

I've played through the complete campaign, the revenge campaign, beat all but one challenges, unlocked all cards for two decks but still there are decks such as "Mind Maze" that I cannot play with.

How do I unlock those?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To unlock those decks, go to any campaign map, and click on the icon on the bottom right to go to a menu where you can unlock and fight various planeswalkers.  Each of them uses a pretty good deck, including mind maze.

[image]

Comment: Ah, thanks a bunch. Somehow forgot about that button :D